# Portion in life after death for Muslims

Tags: halacha

I am a Muslim can I have a Good portion in life after death according to Judaism.
What is the best portion for us according to Judaism if we acknowledge that there is only one God. we believe in the same G-d of Israel.

Comment: Jewish tradition holds that gentiles who live according to the 7 Laws of Noach -- found here http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/62221/jewish/Universal-Morality.htm -- receive a share in the World to Come. Unofficially: I remember being shown (by a Chabad rabbi) a textual source stating that righteous gentiles may be eligible for more reward in the Hereafter than Jews.

Comment: @SAH-I was unaware that there was same type of question already there, but I am satisfied by the reference of Chabad Rabbi by SAH.

Comment: @SAH Do you remember where? Or could you ask the person who showed it to you where it is? Because it sounds quite bizarre.

Comment: @user613 I wish! It's definitely surprising. I remember the name of the rabbi (very old learned guy) but not sure if it's appropriate to post it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and I am happy that the gentiles too will have good portions in the live to come.